# How to change validation in nested object using same class in NestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I have a frontend application which sends to my backend application a POST request with the following JSON body

```
{
    "principal": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "birth": "1990-01-01T02:00:00.000Z",
        "phone": "(12) 341 234 124",
        "email": "test@test.com"
    },
    "companion": {
        "name": "",
        "birth": null,
        "phone": "",
        "email": ""
    },
    ... // some other data
}
```

And in my backend application, which I'm using NestJS, since both, `principal` and `companion` have the same properties, I mapped to the following DTO.

```
import { IsNotEmpty, IsString } from "class-validator";

export class NewDataDto {
    principal: PersonDto;
    companion: PersonDto;
    // some other data
}

export class PersonDto {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    name: string;

    birth?: Date;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    phone: string;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    email: string;
}
```

So in the `principal` object, all the properties are required, but in the `companion` object, all properties are optional. Since all the properties are the same in both objects, only the validation changes, how do I validate that using the same class to both objects?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validating-nested-objects?

Comment: Yep, I tried. But I have the 2 objects with different validations that are the same class, so the `name`, for instance, must be required in the `principal` but can be null in the `companion`.

Comment: What about creating separate classes for validation purposes?

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Bruno that it's better to separate classes. And also take a look on mapped types packages from nest js https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types

Comment: Yeah, it's a way to solve it. But violates the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle so hard that discouraged me to follow this solution.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way where I can pass a variable to the constructor of the class and based on the value I could validate all the properties of the object.

Answer (score 1):

So I found an answer to my problem. There is indeed a way to do it. Not using the same class, but not hurting the DRY principals and reusing code. I will post it here, so it could benefit someone that has the same issue.

```
export class PersonDto {
    protected validateRequiredFields = false;
    
    @ValidateIf((o) => o.validateRequiredFields || o.name)
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    name: string;

    birth?: Date;

    @ValidateIf((o) => o.validateRequiredFields || o.phone)
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    phone: string;

    @ValidateIf((o) => o.validateRequiredFields || o.email)
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    email: string;
}

export class PrincipalDto extends PersonDto{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.validateRequiredFields = true;
    }
}

export class NewDataDto {
    @ValidateNested()
    @Type(() => PrincipalDto)
    @IsDefined()
    principal: PrincipalDto;

    @ValidateNested()
    @Type(() => PersonDto)
    companion: PersonDto;

    // some other data
}
```

There are some things to note here.

First, if all the classes are in the same file, you need to declare the classes that has no dependency first.

Second, in the `@ValidateIf` you need to put the `validateRequiredFields` with an OR clause and the field that you are validating, because you want to validate if the field has some value.

Third, when validating the mother class, in my case `NewDataDto`, make sure you are validating `@Type` correctly. And put a `@IsDefined` in the property you want the required fields to be validated.

And last, you can override the `validateRequiredFields` inside the constructor or outside and don't have a constructor in the subclass, and it will work just fine. But I personally like the override in the constructor idea.