# Is it possible to derive a new class from existing class with a decorator applied to every field in the class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, class-validator

Here's an example of a class that I'm validating,
I would like to create a new class with the `@IsOptiona()` decorator applied to each field.

```js
export class CreateCompanyDto {
    @Length(2, 150)
    name: string;

    @IsOptional()
    @IsUrl()
    logoImageUrl: string;

    @IsUrl()
    websiteUrl: string;
}
```

Currently, I have to write it out by hand, but the class is rather large, and it's getting cumbersome to write it all out.

```js
export class UpdateCompanyDto {
    @IsOptional()
    @Length(2, 150)
    name: string;

    @IsOptional()
    @IsUrl()
    logoImageUrl: string;

    @IsOptional()
    @IsUrl()
    websiteUrl: string;
}
```

Is there a way to derive `UpdateCompanyDto` from `CreateCompanyDto` but with `@IsOptional()` applied to each field?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a few days ago and I manage to solve it.

Basically you need to have one class extending the other; use the `@ValidateIf` notation and have a variable to decide if you want to validate the required fields or not.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67125002/how-to-change-validation-in-nested-object-using-same-class-in-nestjs/67149188#67149188) I explain how I did it.